# inconsistent php versions found between 2 ubuntu VMs

Tags: apt, updates, php

We have 2 ubuntu VMs, possibly installed in a different manner, but currently they are both on `16.04.3 LTS` and while doing `sudo apt-get update` they seem to have the same update repositories (although shown in different order):

#### VM 1:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

#### VM 2:

```
Hit:1 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

I also confirm the above by looking into `/etc/apt/sources.list` of both machines.

How is it possible that those 2 machines don't have (or update to) the latest available software versions for various componetns? e.g php is `7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1` on VM 1 and `7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` on VM 2. Also `sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't seem to fetch the `7.0.22` in VM 1.

Things I've tried so far:

- the results of `apt policy` look the same: https://pastebin.com/raw/cVQgbGyv vs https://pastebin.com/raw/1dH4qKZ5
- an `apt install -f` does nothing on both VMs (`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and X not upgraded`)
- `apt-mark showhold` revealed that there are no packages on hold, but still `sudo apt upgrade` results in this https://pastebin.com/raw/ntp6AmyM
- `type -a php` result in `php is /usr/bin/php` in both VMs
- `dpkg -l | grep php` has no differences other than the PHP version: https://pastebin.com/raw/NBLy9myZ vs https://pastebin.com/raw/YMT2rCYy
- `/usr/bin/php -v` on VM 1 results in `PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )` and on VM 2 results in `PHP 7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) (built: May 11 2017 14:06:14) ( NTS )`

A difference I found is via the command `apt-cache policy php7.0-cli`:

VM1:

```
foo@vm1:~$ apt-cache policy php7.0-cli
php7.0-cli:
  Installed: 7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
  Candidate: 7.0.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.0.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.0.4-7ubuntu2 500
        500 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

VM2:

```
foo@vm2:~$ apt-cache policy php7.0-cli
php7.0-cli:
  Installed: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Candidate: 7.0.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.0.25-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.0.4-7ubuntu2 500
        500 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Seems 1 machine has the Ubuntu repositories version of php installed the other the version from ondreij's ppa. One option you have is to uninstall php on the machine with the 0.19 version, remove the ppa and reinstall php.

Comment: @Videonauth you can tell this by the php version numbers? Because the update repositories are 100% the same.

Comment: `7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1` are version numbers ondrei uses.  `7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` are more looking like the one canonical would use. You can verify that if you use `apt policy php` on both machines.

Comment: @Videonauth thanks for that command, looks interesting. Its result though is exactly the same on both VMs: https://pastebin.com/raw/LARFYz8b vs https://pastebin.com/raw/cNrNBksW

Comment: That is a weird output indeed but as you can see in the version tables fpr likely candidates: `1:7.1+55+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 --> http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main` and `1:7.0+35ubuntu6 -->  http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main`.

Comment: Ah i see my error now, you probably installed php7.0 as meta-package. so check for `apt policy php7.0`.

Comment: First, there is no need to use pastebins here; the length of questions is not limited. Second, the output of `dpkg -l | grep php` will give better insights.

Comment: @fkraiem actually, the length of posts is limited to 30000 characters. It's just that the limit is high enough that it is rarely an issue.

Comment: @cherouvim please [edit] your question and include all relevant information here. Also, make it read as though it were written that way from the beginning. We don't need to see "edit:" etc., the objective is to make the question understandable to someone reading it for the first time. That said, your `apt policy` output shows that both machines have the same version of php installed. Therefore, it is most likely a problem with which `php` is found first on your path. Show us the output of `type -a php` on both machines, one of the results should be the right version.

Comment: @fkraiem I used a pastebin for each output with the same formatting and whitespace so one could middle click on each of them and then alternate on the new browser tabs in order to quickly spot the differences (there aren't any).

Comment: @terdon: updated my question with the results of the command you suggested. Both machines are provisioned with the same ansible playbook, so I didn't expect a duplicate php. The only difference is maybe how the vanilla ubuntu vm was installed, and the date on which I provisioned them.

Comment: @fkraiem: updated my question with the results of the command you suggested.

Comment: And does `/usr/bin/php -V` (not just `php -V`) return different results on the two machines? But please stop using pastebins for this. It just makes things harder to understand. Put the `dpkg -l | grep php` results in the question itself. Put *any* output in the question itself unless it makes your post pass the 30000 character limit.

Comment: @terdon executing `/usr/bin/php -v` return different results on the two machines. Updated answer.

Comment: The version of `php7.0` is actually the same on both machines. `apt-cache policy php7.0-cli` might be more helpful.

Comment: @fkraiem thanks, that showed different results. Updated my answer. Does that `***` mean what is selected and everything else is also available in the system?

Comment: Yes, `***` denotes the version currently installed, and the other ones are those that are available from the repositories that are enabled on the system. If you want to upgrade `php7.0-cli` to 7.0.22, try `apt install php7.0-cli=7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`.